# Getting "A generic error occurred in GDI+" in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, save

I wrote a very simple code to get the image from clipboard when the user press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Then I save that image to a static location:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public System.Drawing.Image GetClipboardImage()
    {
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = null;
        if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
        {
            returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
        }
        return returnImage;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            Image img = GetClipboardImage();

            // ******* IT THROWS THE ERROR HERE*****************
            img.Save(@"C:\LOGO_ARTWORK_TEMP_IMAGE.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error when I try to save the image. This program works perfectly on my system but it doesn't work on customer's server. **Is it about permissions**?

Here is the exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at LOGO_IMAGE_COPY_PASTE.Form1.Form1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) in D:\PROJELER\LOGO_IMAGE_COPY_PASTE\LOGO_IMAGE_COPY_PASTE\Form1.cs:line 36
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems unlikely that you'd have write permission to `C:\` on your customer's server.  Can you create a file in there by means other than running your program?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the pasted image data is valid. Then check the permissions and validate that a "C"-drive actually exists. Also check that the firewall isn't preventing the program from creating the file, or if there's already other file with the same name, that prevents the writing.